# C++11 ThreadPool implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading

A new version of this code based on the provided advice can be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/263059/c-threadgroup-implementation).
Latest improvement is found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/263098/c-improved-threadgroup-implementation).

---

I made a simple `ThreadPool` implementation in C++ using only atomics ( neither `std::mutex` nor `std::condition_variable` were used).

The idea is to have a `threads_ready` increasing to `threads.size()` until all threads are finished, and then back to 0 when all threads are ready to execute again. This was the simplest I could think of, that actually works in the given scenario.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cassert>
#include <numeric>

using std::vector;
using std::function;
using std::thread;
using std::mutex;
using std::unique_lock;
using std::atomic;

class ThreadPool{
public:
    ThreadPool(int number_of_threads, function<void(vector<double>&, int, int)> function)
    :  target_buffer(nullptr)
    ,  worker_function(function)
    ,  threads()
    ,  threads_ready(0)
    ,  state(IDLE_VALUE)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < number_of_threads; ++i)
            threads.push_back(thread(&ThreadPool::worker, this, i));
    }

    ~ThreadPool(){
        while(0 < threads_ready.load()); /* Wait until all pending operations finish */

        state.store(END_VALUE);

        while(0 < threads.size()){
            if(true == threads.back().joinable())
                threads.back().join();
            threads.pop_back();
        }
    }

    void start_and_block(vector<double>& buffer){
        /* initialize, start.. */
        target_buffer = &buffer;
        state.store(START_VALUE);

        /* wait until the work is done */
        while(threads.size() > threads_ready.load());
        state.store(IDLE_VALUE);

        /* wait until the threads are available again */
        while(0 < threads_ready.load());
    }

private:
    static const int IDLE_VALUE = 0;
    static const int START_VALUE = 1;
    static const int END_VALUE = 2;

    vector<double>* target_buffer;
    function<void(vector<double>&, int, int)> worker_function; /* buffer, start, length */
    vector<thread> threads;
    atomic<int> threads_ready;
    atomic<int> state; /* 1 = start; 0 = don't start */

    void worker(int thread_index){
        int tmp_num;
        while(END_VALUE != state){ /* Until the pool is stopped */
            while(START_VALUE == state){ /* Wait until start signal is provided */

                worker_function(
                    (*target_buffer),
                    (thread_index * (target_buffer->size()/threads.size())),
                    (target_buffer->size()/threads.size())
                );/* do the work */

                tmp_num = threads_ready.load(); /* signal that work is done! */
                while(!threads_ready.compare_exchange_weak(tmp_num, (tmp_num + 1u)))
                    tmp_num = threads_ready.load(); /* increase "done counter" */

                while(START_VALUE == state.load()); /* Wait until the other threads are finished */

                tmp_num = threads_ready.load(); /* Signal that thread is finished */
                while(!threads_ready.compare_exchange_weak(tmp_num, (tmp_num - 1u)))
                    tmp_num = threads_ready.load(); /* decrease "done counter" */
            } /*while(START_VALUE == state)*/
        } /*while(END_VALUE != state)*/
    }
};

static int result = 0;
static mutex cout_mutex;

void worker(vector<double> buffer, int start, int length){
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i){
        sum += buffer[i];
    }
    std::lock_guard<mutex> my_lock(cout_mutex);
    std::cout << "Partial sum: " << std::setw(4) << sum << " \t\t    |" << "\r";
    result += sum;
}

int main(int argc, char** agrs){
    ThreadPool pool(5,&worker);
    result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i< 10000; ++i){
        vector<double> test_buffer(500, rand()%10);
        result = 0;
        pool.start_and_block(test_buffer);
        std::cout << "result["<< i << "]: " << std::setw(4) << result << " \t\t    |" << "\r";
        assert(std::accumulate(test_buffer.begin(),test_buffer.end(), 0) == result);
    }
    std::cout << "All assertions passed!   |"<< std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

According to the assertions, the behavior is as expected, but is there any dangers/wrong behavior here that I missed?
Is there any way to improve this? How might this put up with real-world usage?

Comment: I wouldn't call this a thread _pool_ - that would imply that calling code could come along and find a running thread to do its work.  Here, we just have a gang of threads that start, do work, and finish.

Comment: Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site.  You could post improved code as a new question, as an answer, or as a link to an external site - as described in [I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body).  I have rolled back the edit, so the answers make sense again.

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep this in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`start_and_block()` is mis-named - call it `start_and_busy_wait()`.  Busy-waiting is inefficient.  Instead of avoiding `std::condition_variable`, embrace it; use it in the slow path instead of `while(threads.size() > threads_ready.load());` and `while(0 < threads_ready.load());`.

Also, it's redundant to compare against literal bools - `if(true == threads.back().joinable())` should be simply `if(threads.back().joinable())`.

Comment: That is not true, the threads also need to be finished and ready, for another potential  ˙start_and_block` call. If the slow path doesn't wait until `threads_ready` is back to 0 there are all kinds of synchronisation problems.

Comment: Is the only way to eliminate busy-waiting condition variables?

Comment: Well the reason was the lack of understanding, but I think a conditional variable could be used in the slow path instead of the `while` cycles, where the predicate would be the same as the condition in the while cycle.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I've made an improved version: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/263059/c11-threadgroup-implementation

Answer (score 1):

Why is the state an `int` rather than an enumerated type?  Your definitions of constants `IDLE_VALUE` etc. looks like it ought to be an enumerated type.  Is this used with values other than those special three?

`while(0 < threads_ready.load());`
Busy waiting is inefficient.  At worst, you may end up with the thread doing the work being pre-empted to run the loop that's waiting for it to finish!  Better to use a `semaphore` to wait for all threads to complete.

```
   :  target_buffer(nullptr)
    ,  worker_function(function)
    ,  threads()
    ,  threads_ready(0)
    ,  state(IDLE_VALUE)
```

Only one of those are initialized with a parameter to the constructor.  The rest can use inline immediate initializers on those members for clearer code and maintenance benefits.

`if(true == threads.back().joinable())`
Testing against `true` is just silly.  Where does it stop?  After all, `operator==` is also returning a `bool` so should you write `true == (true == threads.back().joinable())` ?  Bools are bool.  Your test *is* `if(threads.back().joinable())`.

Your "buffer" is not const so I thought it was going to be for output.  It's not.  That's the work input being split up.  Buffer is a misleading name for this.  You should use *iterators* rather than a collection plus indexes to indicate a group of elements to work on.

Comment: "The rest can use inline immediate initializers on those members for clearer code and maintenance benefits. " - Does that mean, to simply omit them from the constructor, for the members to be zero-initialized?

Comment: The Busy waiting is eliminated in the question linked to this one, and indeed you are right, thank you!

Comment: You are also right about the enumeration, I'll keep this in mind with the next rework, although I only have a vague outline of how I might be using iterators rather than a collection..

Comment: @DavidTóth each worker is given a pair (begin and end) of iterators to define the input elements assigned to it.  Are you familiar with the [standard library algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)?

Comment: I'd much rather we discuss this with the next version I am about to post, it will definately be more specific.