# C++ ThreadGroup Implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading

Edit: An improved code based on feedback is available [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/263098/c-improved-threadgroup-implementation).

---

As a kind of sequel to the previous [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/263022/c11-threadpool-implementation), here is an improved version( with clarified naming ). The Idea is the same: An integer `threads_ready` is increased to threads.size() until all threads are finished with the payload, and then back to 0 when all threads are ready to execute again.

This version has no busy-waiting, and it's more generic because of templates.
Is there any possibility to optimize more? I would think that using atomic for the state is overkill, as mostly it is modified under a mutex, but I couldn't get the program to work without using `atomic`.

I have tried to re-implement this using variable template arguments, but I failed.  I would think it is mainly because the argument for running is provided through pointers.
Would using lambdas be a better solution here? ( Mainly regarding portability, but also in performance )

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cassert>
#include <numeric>
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>

using std::atomic;
using std::vector;
using std::function;
using std::thread;
using std::mutex;
using std::unique_lock;
using std::lock_guard;
using std::condition_variable;

template<typename T>
class ThreadGroup{
public:
    ThreadGroup(int number_of_threads, function<void(T&, int, int)> function)
    :  target_buffer(nullptr)
    ,  worker_function(function)
    ,  threads()
    ,  threads_ready(0)
    ,  state(IDLE_VALUE)
    ,  state_mutex()
    ,  synchroniser()
    {
      for(int i = 0; i < number_of_threads; ++i)
        threads.push_back(thread(&ThreadGroup::worker, this, i));
    }

    ~ThreadGroup(){
      { /* Signal to the worker threads that the show is over */
        lock_guard<mutex> my_lock(state_mutex);
        state.store(END_VALUE);
      }
      while(0 < threads.size()){
        if(threads.back().joinable())
          threads.back().join();
        threads.pop_back();
      }
    }

    void start_and_block(T& buffer){
      { /* initialize, start.. */
        unique_lock<mutex> my_lock(state_mutex);
        target_buffer = &buffer;
        state.store(START_VALUE);
      }

      { /* wait until the work is done */
        unique_lock<mutex> my_lock(state_mutex);
        if(threads.size() > threads_ready)synchroniser.wait(my_lock,[=](){
          return (threads.size() <= threads_ready);
        });
      }
      { /* set appropriate state */
        unique_lock<mutex> my_lock(state_mutex);
        state.store(IDLE_VALUE);
      }
      synchroniser.notify_all(); /* Notify worker threads that the main thread is finished */

      { /* wait until all threads are notified */
        unique_lock<mutex> my_lock(state_mutex);
        if(0 < threads_ready)synchroniser.wait(my_lock,[=](){
          return (0 >= threads_ready); /* All threads are notified once the @threads_ready variable is zero again */
        });
      }
    }

private:
    static const int IDLE_VALUE = 0;
    static const int START_VALUE = 1;
    static const int END_VALUE = 2;

    T* target_buffer;
    function<void(T&, int, int)> worker_function; /* buffer, start, length */
    vector<thread> threads;
    int threads_ready;
    atomic<int> state;
    mutex state_mutex;
    condition_variable synchroniser;

    void worker(int thread_index){
      while(END_VALUE != state.load()){ /* Until the pool is stopped */
        while(START_VALUE == state.load()){ /* Wait until start signal is provided */
          worker_function(
            (*target_buffer),
            (thread_index * (target_buffer->size()/threads.size())),
            (target_buffer->size()/threads.size())
          );/* do the work */

          { /* signal that work is done! */
            unique_lock<mutex> my_lock(state_mutex);
            ++threads_ready; /* increase "done counter" */
          }
          synchroniser.notify_all(); /* Notify main thread that this thread  is finsished */

          { /* Wait until main thread is closing the iteration */
            unique_lock<mutex> my_lock(state_mutex);
            if(START_VALUE == state.load())synchroniser.wait(my_lock,[=](){
              return (START_VALUE != state.load());
            });
          }

          { /* signal that this thread is notified! */
            unique_lock<mutex> my_lock(state_mutex);
            --threads_ready; /* decrease the "done counter" to do so */
          }
          synchroniser.notify_all(); /* Notify main thread that this thread  is finsished */
        } /*while(START_VALUE == state)*/
      } /*while(END_VALUE != state)*/
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** agrs){
  int result = 0;
  mutex cout_mutex;

  ThreadGroup<vector<double>> pool(5,[&](vector<double>& buffer, int start, int length){
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i){
      sum += buffer[i];
    }
    lock_guard<mutex> my_lock(cout_mutex);
    std::cout << "Partial sum: " << std::setw(4) << sum << " \t\t    |" << "\r";
    result += sum;
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200)); //to test with some payload
  });

  result = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i< 10000; ++i){
    vector<double> test_buffer(500, rand()%10);
    result = 0;
    pool.start_and_block(test_buffer);
    {
      lock_guard<mutex> my_lock(cout_mutex);
      std::cout << "result["<< i << "]: " << std::setw(4) << result << "\t\t    " << std::endl;
    }
    assert(std::accumulate(test_buffer.begin(),test_buffer.end(), 0) == result);
  }
  std::cout << "All assertions passed!   "<< std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: not really, I just prefer to keep it lowest as possible, because of portability reasons. I have been using C++14, and I found no features in c++17 that would make me switch. But any relevant feature would make me switch to a higher standard.

Comment: I was able to include multiple arguments into the template by using std::tuple, by using c++14 standard. I'M not sure if I should post the code here , or to a new question ( as there were no suggestions as of yet... ); And even in C++11 there is the index based extract, instead of the type based one I'm using in the improved code... https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get

Comment: "have this implementation variable template arguments"  I don't understand that.  Have this implementation _do_ what?  (missing verb?)

Comment: Right, that's my eNgLuSh, sorry. I'll fix the phrasing.

Comment: The way to implement using template arguments is to pass the function as a parameter, but its _type_ is a template.  Like any of the standard algorithms.  Then you avoid the overhead of the `std::function` and enable inlining.  I don't think inlining is at all useful here, and you need a `std::function` to start the thread anyway, so it's fine as you have it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Fix compiler warnings

Enable compiler warnings and try to fix all of them. There are several unused parameters. You can avoid the warnings by not giving the parameters a name. For example, you can omit the name `start` from the lambda in `main()`:

```
[&](std::vector<double>& buffer, int, int length){...}
```

As for the parameters of `main()` itself, you can use the same trick, or use the other allowed form of [`main()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) that takes no parameters:

```
int main() {
```

The remaining warnings I get are about comparisons between signed and unsigned integers. Use [`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) as the type of `threads_ready`.

## Unconditionally call `wait()`

There is no need to check the condition before calling `wait()` on a condition variable if you are passing a predicate. The first thing `wait()` will do is to execute the predicate to see if it needs to wait at all.

## Prefer default initializers over initializer lists

The constructor of `ThreadGroup` has a large initializer list. Some of them are redundant, and some of them could be replaced by default initializers. The only things that you should have to put in initializer lists normally are things that depend on the parameters passed to the constructor. So:

```
class ThreadGroup {
public:
    ThreadGroup(std::size_t number_of_threads, std::function<void(T&, int, int)> function)
    : worker_function(function)
    {
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < number_of_threads; ++i)
            threads.emplace_back(&ThreadGroup::worker, this, i);
    }

    ...

private:
    T* target_buffer = nullptr;
    std::function<void(T&, int, int)> worker_function;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::size_t threads_ready = 0;
    std::atomic<int> state = {IDLE_VALUE};
    std::mutex state_mutex;
    std::condition_variable synchroniser;
    ...
};
```

Note that we have to use [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) for `std::atomic<int>` here, otherwise the deleted copy constructor would be selected.

## Don't busy-loop

You start worker threads in the constructor, but `state` is initialized to `IDLE_VALUE`. This causes `worker()` to go into a [busy-loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) until `state` changes. Use a condition variable so the worker thread can `wait()` for work to arrive.

## Unconditionally `join()` threads

I don't see why you are checking if threads are joinable or not. Once they are added to `threads`, they are always in a joinable state. So I would change the destructor to:

```
~ThreadGroup() {
    {
        std::lock_guard<mutex> my_lock(state_mutex);
        state.store(END_VALUE);
        // signal a condition variable to ensure idle threads get woken up
    }

    for (auto &thread: threads)
        thread.join();
}
```

## Avoid `using namespace std` or `using std::` in headers

While it is usually safe to use `using namespace std` in a source file, and it's even better to just bring individual elements from `std::` into the global namespace as you did, as soon as you would move the definition of `class ThreadGroup` to a header file, you should not do this anymore, as that will result in unexpected behavior for source files that don't want to use that but do `#include` your header file. It's not that much extra work to type `std::`, and as a bonus you avoid possible confusion when you have things like `function<...> function`, where the variable starts shadowing the type.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions!  I'll have my questions in the following comments.. :)

Comment: Is it best practice to use zero-initialization of a pointer member? should it not be set explicitly nullptr?

Comment: The busy-loop problem can be solved then by using the conditional variable here as well. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: Do I even need to use `threads.clear()` after joining, or it's automagically done by the destructor somehow?

Comment: I don't use namespace std... I explicitly state each variable I'm using at the beginning..

Comment: In my example, the pointer member is initialized explicitly to `nullptr` at the point where it is declared. Yes, the busy-loop can be solved by using the condition variable. You don't need to call `threads.clear()` in the destructor, since it will be destroyed automatically (member variables have their destructor called after the `class`'s destructor function has run, in reverse order of how they were constructed).

Comment: I like this practice, thank you for sharing it with me! Except the initializer of atomic  is deleted; So ( at least with my skills ) I'm forced to include it into the initialization list.

Comment: I have improved upon the previous code based on your feedback. Thank you!

Comment: You can get the atomic initialized properly, if you use braces, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like `enum state_t { Idle, Start, End };` and use the type `state_t` instead of a plain `int` for values of this type.

The first answer already covered the initializers for the constructor in some detail, and I had pointed this out in the answer to your previous post.

`threads.push_back(thread(&ThreadGroup::worker, this, i));`
You are constructing a temporary `std::thread` instance, copying that to the `vector`, and then destroying the temporary.  This is a perfect use for `emplace_back`, where you give it the constructor arguments rather than a temporary constructed object.  (Though I see that `push_back` has an rvalue form and `thread` has a move constructor, so the amount of work is reduced but not simply eliminated.)

`while(0 < threads.size()){`
This is more clearly stated as `(while !threads.empty())`.

`unique_lock<mutex> my_lock(state_mutex);`
I always found it annoying to have to specify the exact mutex type when creating a `lock_guard` or `unique_lock`, as usually the type name is a bit more verbose and specific.  Now, you can use [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) and just let the template automatically determine the argument type: `unique_lock my_lock(state_mutex);`

```
if(threads.size() > threads_ready)synchroniser.wait(my_lock,[=](){
          return (threads.size() <= threads_ready);
```

Are you aware that you are capturing `this`, not the individual members?  I think so, since you are capturing by value and that makes sense for a pointer but not for the vector itself.  It would be better (and safer) to list the captures rather than using a default.  That is, simply `[this]`.  [In fact](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda),

> The implicit capture of `*this` when the capture default is `=` is deprecated. (since C++20)

Comment: Thank you very much!  :) I'd ask some questions in the following comments, if it's okay .. :)

Comment: Well most comments I got to with a bit of googling, thank you! Most, except the ctags one; The way I understand it that would introduce an additional environment dependency here ( as it is a tool )  ?

Comment: I have improved upon the previous code based on your feedback. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, that should have been CTAD.  I updated my answer to include a useful link.  `lock_guard` is the third example.