# C++ Improved ThreadGroup Implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading

After the amazing feedback from [these](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/263022/c11-threadpool-implementation/263078?noredirect=1#comment519332_263078) [questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/263059/c-threadgroup-implementation/263087?noredirect=1#comment519369_263087); I have prepared a third version of the original posted code.

The Idea is the same: An `std::size_t` variable `threads_ready` is increased to threads.size() until all threads are finished with the payload, and then back to 0 when all threads are ready to execute again.

- I eliminated all busy waiting that I could find
- made the class more generic by making the class use of variadic templates.

  - The Best solution would be to have a lambda capture the required context, but unfortunately I couldn't find a way to deter thread related parameters comfortably from a generic lambda. The best I could manage was to reduce the used parameters to "thread index", so each thread would have an idea about the relevant regions in the inputs.
- I made a better use-case to better test the implementation

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iomanip>
#include <numeric>
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>

#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>

using std::atomic;
using std::vector;
using std::function;
using std::tuple;
using std::thread;
using std::mutex;
using std::unique_lock;
using std::lock_guard;
using std::condition_variable;
using std::size_t;

template<typename First, typename ...T>
class ThreadGroup{
public:
    ThreadGroup(int number_of_threads, function<void(tuple<First, T...>&, int)> function)
    :  worker_function(function)
    ,  state(Idle)
    {
      for(int i = 0; i < number_of_threads; ++i)
        threads.emplace_back(thread(&ThreadGroup::worker, this, i));
    }

    ~ThreadGroup(){
      { /* Signal to the worker threads that the show is over */
        lock_guard<mutex> my_lock(state_mutex);
        state.store(End);
      }
      synchroniser.notify_all();
      for(thread& thread : threads) thread.join();
    }

    void start_and_block(tuple<First, T...>& buffer){
      { /* initialize, start.. */
        unique_lock<mutex> my_lock(state_mutex);
        target_buffers = &buffer;
        state.store(Start);
      }
      synchroniser.notify_all(); /* Whip the peons */

      { /* wait until the work is done */
        unique_lock<mutex> my_lock(state_mutex);
        synchroniser.wait(my_lock,[this](){
          return (threads.size() <= threads_ready);
        });
      }
      { /* set appropriate state */
        unique_lock<mutex> my_lock(state_mutex);
        state.store(Idle);
      }
      synchroniser.notify_all(); /* Notify worker threads that the main thread is finished */

      { /* wait until all threads are notified */
        unique_lock<mutex> my_lock(state_mutex);
        synchroniser.wait(my_lock,[this](){
          return (0 >= threads_ready); /* All threads are notified once the @threads_ready variable is zero again */
        });
      }
    }

private:
    enum state_t{Idle, Start, End};

    tuple<First, T...>* target_buffers = nullptr;
    function<void(tuple<First, T...>&, int)> worker_function; /* start, length */
    vector<thread> threads;
    size_t threads_ready = 0;
    atomic<state_t> state;
    mutex state_mutex;
    condition_variable synchroniser;

    void worker(int thread_index){
      while(End != state.load()){ /* Until the pool is stopped */
        { /* Wait until main thread triggers a task */
          unique_lock<mutex> my_lock(state_mutex);
          synchroniser.wait(my_lock,[this](){
            return (Idle != state.load());
          });
        }
        if(End != state.load()){
          worker_function((*target_buffers), thread_index);/* do the work */

          { /* signal that work is done! */
            unique_lock<mutex> my_lock(state_mutex);
            ++threads_ready; /* increase "done counter" */
          }
          synchroniser.notify_all(); /* Notify main thread that this thread  is finsished */

          { /* Wait until main thread is closing the iteration */
            unique_lock<mutex> my_lock(state_mutex);
            synchroniser.wait(my_lock,[this](){
              return (Start != state.load());
            });
          }

          { /* signal that this thread is notified! */
            unique_lock<mutex> my_lock(state_mutex);
            --threads_ready; /* decrease the "done counter" to do so */
          }
          synchroniser.notify_all(); /* Notify main thread that this thread  is finsished */
        } /* Avoid segfault at destruction */
      } /*while(END_VALUE != state)*/
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** agrs){
  const int number_of_threads = 5;
  vector<double> test_buffer;
  double expected;
  double result = 0;
  mutex cout_mutex;

  ThreadGroup<vector<double>&> pool(number_of_threads,[&](tuple<vector<double>&>& inputs, int thread_index){
    double sum = 0;
    vector<double>& used_buffer = std::get<vector<double>&>(inputs);
    size_t length = (used_buffer.size() / number_of_threads) + 1u;
    size_t start = length * thread_index;
    length = std::min(length, (used_buffer.size() - start));
    if(start < used_buffer.size()) /* More threads could be available, than needed */
      for(size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) sum += used_buffer[start + i];
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200)); //to test with some payload
    { /* Print partial results and accumulate the full results */
      lock_guard<mutex> my_lock(cout_mutex);
      std::cout << "Partial sum[" << thread_index << "]: " << std::setw(4) << sum << " \t\t    \r";
      result += sum;
    }
  });

  for(int i = 0; i< 1000; ++i){
    test_buffer = vector<double>(rand()%500);
    std::for_each(test_buffer.begin(),test_buffer.end(),[](double& element){
      element = rand()%10;
    });
    expected = std::accumulate(test_buffer.begin(),test_buffer.end(), 0.0);
    result = 0;
    auto tpl = std::forward_as_tuple(test_buffer);
    pool.start_and_block(tpl);
    std::cout << "result["<< i << "]: " << std::setw(4) << result << "\t\t    \r";
    assert(expected == result);
  }
  std::cout << "All assertions passed!   "<< std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Is there anything else that could be optimized/improved with this implementation?

Comment: I don't see why the `function` needs all those parameters.  It should only take the thread ID, and anything else it needs would be lambda captures when making that specific function.

Comment: Hmm right, the lambda function can be provided as a pointer through the `start_and_block` function!

Comment: Isn't providing a lambda at runtime inefficient? Are lambdas used like that created at program start, or a new lambda ( of the same functionality ) is created at every call?

Comment: the constructor arguments are the captured values.  It's no more work than creating the tuple to pass into the function.

Comment: Well I couldn't make it work like that... (Despite the example not containing such scenario, the intended usage did).. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68019488/how-to-bind-reference-of-non-movable-object-in-variadic-template-arguments

Comment: You shouldn't need variadic anything.  **Just declare the `function` to take the thread ID.**  What the specific function actually needs will be handled by the lambda capture for that specific use.

Comment: You're right, this is something I could accept as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lambdas are not inefficient.**  You need to pack up those values *somehow*, and the way lambda captures work are just constructor arguments.  That is, it copies the desired values into storage locations, which is exactly the work needed when passing a parameter (storing it into a local variable in the called function).  Your `tuple` packs up values into the tuple, which is morally the same as a structure with unnamed members; again, assuming no extra copies are being made, that is the same amount of work again.

The most straightforward solution is to declare your `function` to just take the thread ID, and pass in a lambda that captures whatever it needs for the actual function to be performed.

We hope that (in a release build anyway) that the constructor argument gets optimized out.  But in the case where you are capturing something like `vector` or `string`, you want to use `move` semantics.  To this end, the constructor argument should be a "sink" parameter.  That is, declare it to take by-value, and use `std::move` in the member initialization.  In any case, you can play around in Compiler Explorer to make sure that the extra copy is actually optimized away.  In practice, copying a few bytes is nothing compared to the cost of starting a thread or synchronizing anything!  As long as you are not deep-copying something expensive like `vector` it's not inefficient.

To clarify:
`ThreadGroup x { 5, [=](int id){  } };`  will initialize the lambda's body (the captures) directly in the `function` parameter of the constructor.
Then, `: worker_function{std::move(function)}` in that constructor will initialize the class member.  That extra copying is what we hope to optimize out:  store the captures directly into the final resting place inside the lambda inside the `std::function` inside the `ThreadGroup`.  Using *move* semantics ensures that even if copies are not entirely eliminated, it will not do expensive deep copies.